# Why isn't my Vue.js WYSIWYG Editor tagging correctly?

Tags: vue.js, wysiwyg

I'm trying to create a simple wysiwyg-Editor with Vue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-tree-b0ullo?file=/src/components/FormatEditor.vue

When I'm trying to tag something, then it's working well for the first time. But if I try it again, then it's not doing it correctly anymore.

Can anyone tell me, what I'm doing wrong?